# Converting Hex Value to SolidColorBrush in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm trying to write an `IValueConverter` in Silverlight. This `IValueConverter` will return a `SolidColorBrush`. The converter will be passed a hex value like "FFFF5300". Because Silverlight does not have the `BrushConverter` class, I needed to parse this value manually. In an attempt to do this, I have the following code:

```
byte a = (byte)(Convert.ToUInt32(color.Substring(0, 2), 16));
byte r = (byte)(Convert.ToUInt32(color.Substring(2, 2), 16));
byte g = (byte)(Convert.ToUInt32(color.Substring(4, 2), 16));
byte b = (byte)(Convert.ToUInt32(color.Substring(6, 2), 16));
```

My problem is, I can't use the `Convert.ToX` methods in an `IValueConverter`. Because of this, I'm not sure how to convert a two character string into a byte value. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: XAML already supports colors in hex format by prefixing it with "#" (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.aspx), are you sure you need this?

Comment: You can certainly use Convert.XX in a Value Converter. Why are you under the impression that you cannot? You just can't cast the value parameter to another type. In the conversion above I would use `Convert.ToByte()`

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can use the `Convert.ToXXX()` methods in an `IValueConverter`. You just need to add the `System` namespace in front of `Convert`: `System.Convert.ToXXX()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this what you're asking, but the following code doesn't use `Convert`:

```
byte a = byte.Parse(color.Substring(0, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

The value must be in the following format "#xxxxxxxx",

```
System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Value);
```

Comment: That method will output a System.Drawing.Color. For Silverlight, he probably wants a System.Windows.Media.Color.

Comment: But System.Drawing.Color can be easily converted to System.Windows.Media.Color                    System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B)